# how to read bar code image as programmatic?

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use iPhone Camera as Bar Code Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342834/how-to-use-iphone-camera-as-bar-code-scanner)

hi all How do we do programmatic reading of a barcode that is captured using a mobile phone camera? For example, how do that using iPhone? Do we need separate hardware to read bar code or can we do image manipulation? help me to solve the problem in iphone.

give the guide for how to use outside api to read the bar code as programmatic in iphone.

Comment: You have to use  out side api for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look At the following links

[RedLaser](http://redlaser.com/sdk/)

[Softek Barcode Reader SDK](http://www.bardecode.com/en/products/200-barcode-reader-sdk-for-the-iphone.html)

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

There are open source libraries available which does this. Y can't use the same?

"Zbar" framework is one such.

Comment: This looks like a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: :) Look into Zbar framework. It should help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to comment on your question, but there is a possible duplicate here, [How to use iPhone Camera as Bar Code Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342834/how-to-use-iphone-camera-as-bar-code-scanner)

Also, you might do well to use a third party library. If you are looking to learn, then have a look around google :) The ZBar library, for example, is hosted on source forge.